# Variable in It spec text always 0 although changed in BeforeEach in ginkgo/gomega

Tags: go, go-testing, ginkgo, gomega

In my code snippet below or https://play.golang.org/p/tLld-zNF2zp, `testValue` was declared inside `Describe` block, changed in `BeforeEach` block. Then, used in.

1. `It`
2. `Expect`

The test passes as expected. From the debug log, `It` always shows `testValue should be 0` instead of `testValue should be` **3**

```
package awesomeProject1_test

import (
    "fmt"
    . "github.com/onsi/ginkgo"
    . "github.com/onsi/gomega"
)

var _ = Describe("AwesomeProject1", func() {
    var testValue int
    BeforeEach(func() {
        testValue = 3
    })
    Context("Correctness of testValue", func() {
        It(fmt.Sprintf("testValue should be %d", testValue), func() {
            Expect(testValue).To(Equal(3))
        })
    })
})
```

Why is `testValue` not changed in `It` statement but inside it?

Answer (score 0):

From [ginkgo](https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/) docs, another `Describe` wraps `Context` functions :

```
var _ = Describe("Book", func() {
    var (
        longBook  Book
        shortBook Book
    )

    BeforeEach(func() {
        longBook = Book{
            Title:  "Les Miserables",
            Author: "Victor Hugo",
            Pages:  2783,
        }

        shortBook = Book{
            Title:  "Fox In Socks",
            Author: "Dr. Seuss",
            Pages:  24,
        }
    })

    //Describe wrapping context
    Describe("Categorizing book length", func() {
        Context("With more than 300 pages", func() {
            It("should be a novel", func() {
                Expect(longBook.CategoryByLength()).To(Equal("NOVEL"))
            })
        })

        Context("With fewer than 300 pages", func() {
            It("should be a short story", func() {
                Expect(shortBook.CategoryByLength()).To(Equal("SHORT STORY"))
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't get how this answers my question. Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

```golang
package ginkgo_test

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"

    . "github.com/onsi/ginkgo"
    . "github.com/onsi/gomega"
)

var _ = Describe("AwesomeProject1", func() {
    var testValue int
    BeforeEach(func() {
        testValue = 3
    })
    Context("Correctness of testValue", func() {
        It(fmt.Sprintf("testValue should be %d", testValue), func() {
            Expect(testValue).To(Equal(3))
        })
    })
})

func TestGoStudy(t *testing.T) {
    RegisterFailHandler(Fail)
    RunSpecs(t, "GoStudy Suite")
}
```

```sh
=== RUN   TestGoStudy
Running Suite: GoStudy Suite
============================
Random Seed: 1634629701
Will run 1 of 1 specs

•
Ran 1 of 1 Specs in 0.000 seconds
SUCCESS! -- 1 Passed | 0 Failed | 0 Pending | 0 Skipped
--- PASS: TestGoStudy (0.00s)
PASS

Process finished with the exit code 0
```

I have test your code and code worked well.

My test environment:

```
go version go1.17.1
github.com/onsi/ginkgo v1.16.5 
github.com/onsi/gomega v1.16.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I also tested my code and it worked the same as yours. It's just that when I used `debug` in my IDE, the debug log showed `testValue should be 0` instead of `testValue should be 3`